# jquery step by step form

Tags: jquery, forms, fadein

on my demo I have a step by step form, I need to fix the breadcrumb navigation withing the **active** class

it's all working fine, but the active on the menu doesn't seems to be working . 
could you give a quick look for me please?

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/75/

```
(function () {
    var prevLink = '<input class="button cancel" type="button" value="cancel">';
    var nextLink = '<input class="button continue" type="button" value="Continue">';
    var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' + prevLink + nextLink + '</div>';
    var FormData = [];

    $(function() {
        // init
        $('#stepbystep > fieldset').hide().append(navHTML);
        $('#first-step .cancel').remove();
        $('#last-step .continue').remove();

        // show first step
        $('#first-step').show();

        $('input.continue').click(function() {
            var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            $('.breadcrumb a').addClass('active');

            if (whichStep == 'first-step') { }
            else if (whichStep == 'second-step') { }
            else if (whichStep == 'third-step') { }
            else if (whichStep == 'fourth-step') { }
            else if (whichStep == 'last-step') { }

            $(this).parent().parent().hide(300).next().show(300);
            $('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');
        });

        $('input.cancel').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide(300).prev().show(300);

        });
    })
}());
```

Comment: I Believe your problem is the Postback. Try save the variable in a hidden input so you can in the load refresh the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below function in your code,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/xSkgH/83/)

```
    function updateBreadCrumb (whichStep, isCancel) {
       var bc = 1;
       if (isCancel) bc = -1;
       $('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');

       if (whichStep == 'second-step') {
           bc += 1;
        } else if (whichStep == 'third-step') {
           bc += 2;
        } else if (whichStep == 'fourth-step') {
           bc += 3;
        } else if (whichStep == 'last-step') {
           bc += 4;
        }
        $('.breadcrumb a:eq('+bc+')').addClass('active');
    }
```

And then call them accordingly as below,

```
   //Inside Continue click
   updateBreadCrumb ( whichStep, false);

   //Inside Cancel click
   updateBreadCrumb ( whichStep, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is because the code is this:

```
$('.breadcrumb a').addClass('active');
// other stuff
$('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');
```

So every time you click the Continue button, you make every link in the breadcrumb `active` and then almost immediately (that is, within the same function) make them all not `active`.  If you step through a debugger you can see their styles change and then change back.

If you want to make a specific element `active` then you're going to have to identify that specific element in some way.  Essentially, you'd want to start the function with this:

```
$('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');
```

That way you "de-activate" whichever one is `active` (since you don't care which one was active, so just hit all of them).  Then you'll need to identify the specific element on which you want to add the `active` class.  That might be a little trickier.

Maybe give each one an `id` so you can reference them directly?  Or, since you seem to already have a concept of "first step" and "second step" and so on, you can reference them with something like this:

```
$('.breadcrumb a').eq(2).addClass('active');
```

This would reference the third element in the matched elements (index `2`), so it would be applicable on "step three."

Comment: omg I am so sleep that I miss that =X +1

Comment: @DD77: I imagine your function would start by removing the classes (currently it starts by adding the classes), then you'd add the class to the appropriate element in your `if/else if/else if/etc.` construct where you determine the current step of the process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are targeting all of the breadcrumb links:

```
   $('.breadcrumb a').addClass('active');
```

You probably want to give the links an id and then add the class in the if statement.

```
   var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
   // remove active from all links then add back the to the step you are on    
   $('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');

   if (whichStep == 'first-step') { 
     $('.breadcrumb #stepOne').addClass('active');
   }
```